# Javascript supermarket test app

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

I have created this supermarket application with JavaScript. It has a pre-defined aisle information. The user then gives the script 3 items and the categories to which they belong. If a category matches one of the pre-defined ones, the script tells you where your item is located.

I was wondering whether there was a more **efficient** way to loop through, store, and compare this data? Should I be using arrays or objects here?

```
var safeway = {};
safeway.aisle1 = {
    contents: "fresh produce",
    aisle: "Aisle 1"
};
safeway.aisle2 = {
    contents: "meat and seafood",
    aisle: "Aisle 2"
};
safeway.aisle3 = {
    contents: "dairy",
    aisle: "Aisle 3"
};
safeway.aisle4 = {
    contents: "snacks",
    aisle: "Aisle 4"
};
safeway.aisle5 = {
    contents: "beverages",
    aisle: "Aisle 5"
};
safeway.aisle6 = {
    contents: "frozen foods",
    aisle: "Aisle 6"
};
safeway.aisle7 = {
    contents: "condiments and ingredients",
    aisle: "Aisle 7"
};

li1 = prompt("List Item 1");
li1Category = prompt("What category does this item belong to?");


li2 = prompt("List Item 2");
li2Category = prompt("What category does this item belong to?");


li3 = prompt("List Item 3");
li3Category = prompt("What category does this item belong to?");


var list = {};

list.item1 = {
item: li1,
category: li1Category
};

list.item2 = {
item: li2,
category: li2Category
};

list.item3 = {
item: li3,
category: li3Category
};

var match = function() {
    for(var i in list) {
        for(var x in safeway) {
            if(list[i].category === safeway[x].contents) {
                console.log("The " + list[i].item + " is in " + safeway[x].aisle);
        }
    }

}
};
match();
```

Comment: Use a `contents -> aisle` map, rather than an `aisle -> contents` map. Then you can  get the aisle for a specific category with `safeway[list[i].category].aisle` (assuming the category exists of course, you should probably account for non-existing categories as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the safeway object with contents (category) key and aisle value to search an aisle by contents (category) (assuming that a category can be only in one aisle).

And, the list in your code can be an array.

```
var safeway = {};

safeway['fresh produce'] = 'Aisle 1';

safeway['meat and seafood'] = 'Aisle 2';

var list = [];

var li = 'beef';
var liCategory = 'meat and seafood';

list.push({
    item: li,
    category: liCategory
});

li = 'some item';
liCategory = 'some category';

list.push({
    item: li,
    category: liCategory
});

function match(items, store) {
    var foundAisle;
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        foundAisle = store[items[i].category];
        item = items[i].item;
        if (foundAisle) {
            console.log("The " + item + " is in " + foundAisle);
        } else {
            console.log("The " + item + " is not found");
        }
    }
};

match(list, safeway);

The beef is in Aisle 2
The some item is not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "safeway" as a JavaScript object.
I would say JSON format is more efficient way to store data. So that you can easily parse your huge data using jQuery or PHP, etc.